# Ayuda con script Batch

Tags: cmd, batch

estoy intentando hacer un script batch para generar rutas de algunos proyectos o carpetas, mi código es el siguiente:

```
@echo off 
title Rutas de Proyectos
echo [1] Solatino ASP.NET y Angular
echo [2] Solatino Web con Angular
set/a a=1
set/a b=2

set/p opcion=Que proyecto:
if %opcion% equ a (
    goto :RutaSolnet
)
if %opcion% equ b (
    goto :RutasolAngular
  )

:RutaSolnet 
CD C:\Users\PC\documents\solatinotours\web\ 
:RutasolAngular
CD C:\Users\PC\documents\solatinoAngular\
```

La cosa es que no importa si pongo en "opción" el valor 1 o 2, siempre me devuelve la última ruta, en este caso llama  a RutasolAngular, y así pasa si voy agregando más rutas, nunca me devuelve la ruta que debería. ¿Alguién podría ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola quizás te funcionaría poner un `GOTO End` al finalizar cada cambio de directorio y al final del script poner `:End`.

```
:RutaSolnet

CD C:\Users\PC\documents\solatinotours\web\
GOTO End

:RutasolAngular

CD C:\Users\PC\documents\solatinoAngular\
GOTO End

:End
```

Recuerda agregar una linea en blanco adicional al final del script si este va a terminar con `:End`

Comment: Agregué el GOTO END tal como dijiste, me funcionó excelente. Muchas gracias broder.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 
title Rutas de Proyectos
echo [1] Solatino ASP.NET y Angular
echo [2] Solatino Web con Angular
set/a a=1
set/a b=2

set/p opcion=Que proyecto:
if %opcion% equ a (
    goto :RutaSolnet
)
if %opcion% equ b (
    goto :RutasolAngular
  )

:RutaSolnet 
CD C:\Users\PC\documents\solatinotours\web\ 
pause>nul
:RutasolAngular
CD C:\Users\PC\documents\solatinoAngular\
pause>nul
```

Pasa de la primera etiqueta a la segunda debido a que no habías pausado o redireccionado el código a otro lugar, con el pause>nul no pasaría a la siguiente etiqueta hasta que pulses una tecla, puedes cambiarlo un goto a otra etiqueta, un exit para salir...